# How do I save the correct NSManagedObjectContext without using a singleton?

Tags: swift, core-data, singleton, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my app, I moved the Core Data stack out of AppDelegate and into its own class called `LiftEventDataManager`. There are a few classes in which I get a reference to this stack and, of course, each time I do a new `NSManagedObjectContext` is created. These references are used to do things like pull some default application data from the db to present in a view (e.g. a list of the user's choices).

When the initial `viewController` is presented, my `viewModel` asks my `LiftEventDataManager`for a new object to back the view. The user's input is used to set the properties of this object and when they're done, I want to save the object. However, the object isn't being saved.

When the user taps save, the `viewModel` uses its reference to `LiftEventDataManager` and calls this function (Swift 2.3):

```
func saveLiftEvent() {
  do {
    try moc!.save()
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LiftEventDidSave", object: nil)
}
```

I believe the object is not being saved because it was created by my `viewModel` asking the `LiftEventDataManager` for a new object which would have a `managedObjectContext`, but the save is called being by the `LiftEventDataManager` that I presume is getting a *new* reference to the Core Data stack. I suppose I could get the object's `managedObjectContext` with:

```
let moc = newLiftEvent.managedObjectContext
```

and then pass it to the `saveLiftEvent(moc: NSManagedObjectContext)`.

Have I answered my own question about how to save it properly or is there a flaw in my design? Keep in mind please that I don't want to use a singleton.

Comment: You need always the same instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` that's why Apple left the Core Data stack in AppDelegate. The alternative is indeed a ... singleton. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Darn. Thanks @vadian. I've corrected it now.

Comment: My app is relatively simple so I don't have any of the concerns that would call for a singleton. I also don't want to make my code more complex than it needs to be or deal with the hassles it creates for unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have some way of passing the `NSManagedObjectContext` along. A singleton is one way to do it, but it certainly isn't the only way to do it.

It sounds like you're creating a new instance of `LiftEventDataManager` every time you need one. Instead of creating a new instance, can you pass along the existing instance using dependency injection of some sort?

If the view model has a reference to the data manager, that might be a good place to centralize things without making a singleton.

Comment: You're right, Dave. That's what I'm doing and it's what's causing my problem. I've been researching a lot since I asked my question and I think dependency injection is the way to go. The concept is simple, but there's one unanswered part of the question if I go that route. My understanding is that I pass the context around from one view controller to the next. Does it matter how I do that. For example, I have a couple of utility classes that need it. Does that mean I probably need to modify the interfaces between them so I'm passing that context when needed?

Comment: In my experience, CoreData is the type of framework that easily entangles itself in all of your code, so it can be difficult to make changes later. Directly passing CoreData objects between your VCs tightly couples them to your data layer. If CoreData is hidden behind your own view model or thinly abstracted persistence layer, then you retain more flexibility. If you have more specific questions I'm happy to try to answer more concretely.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Here's where I get stuck. You seem to know what you're doing because you have something I don't have; experience. Then someone else who knows what they're doing says VCs control the flow of iOS apps so they are where you pass the context around. If you're up to it, I'm Bluesman in the comments of this post: https://cocoacasts.com/building-the-perfect-core-data-stack-passing-it-around/ It would be really helpful to know what you think about it.